# In Oracle Apex how to place multiple links in a single column value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need a column to have three icon links, "View", "Edit", and "Delete", like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmOCn.jpg)

I can't do this by setting the column type to Link as that only works if you want the column to have a single link whereas I need it to have three in this case. I'm guessing this can be accomplished by adding some html code to the table's SQL query but what should this code be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic report based on Scott's `DEPT` table with additional column that contains 3 link icons. The first two lead to search engines on the Internet, while the last one shows how to call a page in your own application (basically, you have to create URL to page you want to navigate to - I'm navigating to page 5).

```
select deptno, dname, loc,
  --
  '<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" ><span class="fa fa-materialized-view"        > </span></a>' || '&nbsp' ||
  '<a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="fa fa-edit"                     > </span></a>' || '&nbsp' ||
  '<a href="' || apex_page.get_url(p_page => 5) || '"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"> </span></a>'
  as col
from dept
order by deptno
```

Go to `col` column's properties and disable "**Escape special characters**" property.

When ran, page looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Also note: This is how to pass values to items in the target page: p_items  => 'P11_EVENT_ID,P11_UNIQUE_CREATED_EVENT_ID',

            p_values => CREATED_TASK_ID||','||TASK||','||TASK_ID

Comment: ... as described in documentation. There are (many) more arguments to GET_URL function.